# "Generate Scripts" in SSMS 2008 doesn't script indexes and triggers by default

Tags: sql-server-2008

I noticed that "Generate Scripts" in SSMS 2008 doesn't script indexes and triggers by default. I know this can be changed in SSMS options but why would anyone want to omit these 2 important parts (especially triggers) when scripting database? What is the logic behind this implementation?

Comment: You want a use case? Or a full explanation? I can do the first...

Answer (score 1):

One case when you don't want them

[How to transfer a database from one collation to another collation in SQL Server](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/325335) (MS KB)

Step 4a for SQL Server 2000 (my bold)

> Generate scripts for all the objects **(not including the indexes, the triggers, the primary keys, the foreign keys, the default settings, and the constraints)**. Additionally, make sure that you enable the Only script 7.0 compatible features option to remove the COLLATE clause from the script.

Comment: +1 - I find it annoying sometimes but it's better to have to select it as an option that to always have it included.  It will <almost> never hurt to omit but could hurt to include.

Comment: @JNK: folk like us would use Red Gate or such anyway rather than SSMS for serious scripting (eg for a SVN folder)

Comment: I actually can't use third party tools unfortunately.  I did write a powershell script to script out objects for me, though :)

Comment: Is this an employer restriction? I'd suggest showing them how long it took to write your powershell script (and any fixes you've done to it in the meantime) and then show them the price tag of SQL Compare. Unless you're a volunteer, have a lot of time to kill, or do this in your spare time, they should be able to calculate cost/benefit pretty quickly. :-)